# How do I add a port number in a href?

Tags: javascript, href

I am trying to add a specific port number to a href in javascript but the end result is the application adds an extra path to the beginning of the href which ends up in a CANNOT GET error.
I am on url: `https://10.xx.xx.xx/a/b`
I click on a button with the href set to
`href = ":10635/hello.html"`

I expect/want to go to `//10.xx.xx.xx:10635/hello`
Instead, I end up going to `//10.xx.xx.xx/a:10635/hello` and getting the CANNOT GET error.

When I set my href to `href = "/hello.html"` , I end up going to `https://10.xx.xx.xx/hello.html` which is a non-existent page but it does not appear to add the `/a` in the url. Looks like the href needs to always start with a `/`?

Any advice on how I can get the port number added to the url ?

Comment: You would need to use the full address to add a port number, meaning `protocol://host:port/page`.  A relative path won't work because a relative path will use the current protocol, host, and port.

Comment: This is how my href is set. The button is on page https://10.xx.xx.xx.xx/a/b    a.getHelp(href="/:10635/hello.html",onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=700')") Help

Comment: Thanks Devon. That worked. I would need to add some more code to achieve that, but I guess it is what it is. Thanks again

Comment: I think this link is helpful. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp